# Typescript: Parameters with rest readonly array give never

Tags: typescript

I create simple sum function that accept rest nums readonly array and try get that function parameters types but with readonly array its give `never` type.

```js
function sum(...nums: readonly number[]): number {
    return nums.reduce((num, sum) => sum += num, 0);
}

const result = smm (1, 2, 3);
console.log('Result:', result);

type SumFnParams = Parameters<typeof sum>; // Why "never"?
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAWzQCgHS7O5ALkQCcBTAQwBMEAbAT0XzQCMySBtAXQEpjm2JRAG8AUIgmkyUECSTNk2clRAQymTMwA0KdD0QBeAHy60iANQGm6HQAYeAblEBfUaIgJkUKalrerqBiImACMOgBMOgDMju6ecLRk2LRwAOaYAOQASmS%20UIQZOuR5saJQ9AAOZIgAyuhoAGJgAAoUJBRoyIaIre1o0uzIADzlVXDApmZGDogA9LOIAOoAFowARGBkAG7sawD8QA)

Why when using `readonly array` for rest param `SumFnParams` type is `never`?

(Without readonly its number[])

Comment: This appears to be a compiler bug. When you type `type X = typeof summ extends ((...args: infer P) => any) ? P : never` then mouse over `args`, it says `...args: P extends unknown[]`, which is obviously wrong since `readonly unknown[]` doesn't extend `unknown[]`, but Typescript thinks that varargs should always be mutable arrays.

Comment: but with or w/o readonly give the same `(parameter) args: P extends unknown[]`

Comment: and `type D = typeof summ extends (...args: (infer P)[]) => any ? P[] : never;` will give correct type regardless readonly or not.

Comment: Relevant issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37193

Comment: Side note: rest parameter is replaced with a "standard" JavaScript array